# how much should i need to know about the blockchain to start programming my smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity

ive been recently interested in NFT projects, should I go deeper in the blockchain before learning how to develop a smart contract or is the basics enough for me to get going

Answer (score 0):

You dont need alot to start but there is some very important thing to know especially in the aspect of security so your assets will be safe.

Solidity is a great and easy language to write smart contract and its really not hard to master, especially if you got some experience in programming languages, i will say that it will take around 2 weeks to learn it from top to botttom.

The blockchain is a deep subject but you dont have to know alot about it to start writing smart contracts.

The important thing to really understand, like i already mentioned, is how to create a safe code that will keep your assets safe.

You can find good courses of solidity in youtube and udemy.